# How to refer target of another folder in terrform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

The terraform structure of my project is:

```
iam/policies/policy1.tf
iam/roles/roles1.tf
```

policy1.tf includes several policies, etc.:

```
resource "aws_iam_policy" "policy1A" {
  name   = "..."
  policy = "${data.template_file.policy1ATempl.rendered}"
}
```

roles1.tf includes several roles, etc.:

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "role1" {
  name               = ....
  assume_role_policy = ....
}
```

Now I want to attach policy1A to role1. Since policy1 and role1 are not in the same folder, how do I attach them?

```
resource "aws_iam_policy_attachment" "attach1" {
  name       = "attachment1"
  roles      = ??? (sth. like ["${aws_iam_role.role1.name}"])
  policy_arn = ??? (sth. like "${aws_iam_policy.Policy1.arn}")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't make references like this across directories because Terraform only works in one directory at a time. If you really do need to separate these into different folders (which I would recommend against here) then normally you would use data sources to retrieve information about resources that have already been created.

In this case though the [`aws_iam_policy` data source](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/iam_policy.html) is currently pretty much useless because it requires the ARN of the policy instead of the path or name. Instead you can construct it if you know the policy name as it fits a well known pattern. You obviously know the name of role(s) you want to attach the policy to and you know the name of the policy so that covers those things.

```
data "aws_caller_identity" "current" {}

resource "aws_iam_policy_attachment" "attach1" {
  name       = "attachment1"
  roles      = "role1"
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}:policy/policy1A"
}
```

This above example does briefly show off how to use data sources as it fetches the AWS account ID, using the [`aws_caller_identity` data source](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/caller_identity.html), and dynamically uses that to build the ARN of the policy you are trying to attach.

I would echo the warning in the docs against using the resource [`aws_iam_policy_attachment`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/iam_policy_attachment.html) unless you are absolutely certain with what you're doing because it will detach the policy from anything else it happens to be attached to. If you want to take a managed policy and attach it to N roles I would instead recommend using [`aws_iam_role_policy_attachment`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/iam_role_policy_attachment.html) and it's like instead.

Comment: Thanks ydaetskcoR. good to know aws_caller_identity and the limitation of aws_iam_policy_attachment. you said "If you really do need to separate these into different folders (which I would recommend against here)". why you are against? what if I maintain a lot of policies and roles of my company so I have to organize them in seperate folders: /policies and /roles, some policies are attached to multiple roles so I cannot store one policy with one role in the same folder? in this case, I have to use your answer to handle that.

Comment: Then you definitely need to be using the `aws_iam_role_policy_attachment`. I separate managed policies into a separate folder but create roles, instance profiles and role attachments when I create the thing that needs them. The users/instances that then create the instances/ASGs etc have tight permissions that allow them to create and manage roles and instance profiles but only attach whitelisted IAM policies for the policies the thing they are creating needs. So in that case you only need to split out the shared IAM policies and then do something like my above answer.

Comment: ydaetskcoR: Ok. so it depends. Thanks