# Separate the AWS IAM policy and reference and attach it in a different folder via Terraform

Tags: terraform, amazon-iam, terraform-provider-aws, was, terraform-aws-modules

I have sample code below which creates an IAM role, a policy document, attachment of policy document and then the attachment of that policy to role.

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "aws_snsANDsqsTeam" {
  name               = "aws_snsANDsqsTeam"
  assume_role_policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.production-okta-trust-relationship.json
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "sns-and-sqs-policy" {
  statement {
    sid    = "AllowToPublishToSns"
    effect = "Allow"
    actions = [
      "sns:Publish",
    ]
    resources = [
      data.resource.arn,
    ]
  }
  statement {
    sid    = "AllowToSubscribeFromSqs"
    effect = "Allow"
    actions = [
      "sqs:changeMessageVisibility*",
      "sqs:SendMessage",
      "sqs:ReceiveMessage",
      "sqs:GetQueue*",
      "sqs:DeleteMessage",
    ]
    resources = [
      data.resource.arn,
    ]
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "sns-and-sqs" {
  name   = "sns-and-sqs-policy"
  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.sns-and-sqs-policy.json
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "sns-and-sqs-role" {
  role       = "aws_snsANDsqsTeam"
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.sns-and-sqs.arn
}
```

Now below is the directory tree that I am trying to get
[image]

Now I want the policy document and policy code to be moved to the developer.tf file under shared/iam folder so it will look like this

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "sns-and-sqs-policy" {
  statement {
    sid    = "AllowToPublishToSns"
    effect = "Allow"
    actions = [
      "sns:Publish",
    ]
    resources = [
      data.resource.arn,
    ]
  }
  statement {
    sid    = "AllowToSubscribeFromSqs"
    effect = "Allow"
    actions = [
      "sqs:changeMessageVisibility*",
      "sqs:SendMessage",
      "sqs:ReceiveMessage",
      "sqs:GetQueue*",
      "sqs:DeleteMessage",
    ]
    resources = [
      data.resource.arn,
    ]
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "sns-and-sqs" {
  name   = "sns-and-sqs-policy"
  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.sns-and-sqs-policy.json
}
```

and have the role creation and policy attachment code in main.tf file under iam-platform-security folder, so the code will look like this:

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "aws_snsANDsqsTeam" {
  name               = "aws_snsANDsqsTeam"
  assume_role_policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.production-okta-trust-relationship.json
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "sns-and-sqs-role" {
  role       = "aws_snsANDsqsTeam"
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.sns-and-sqs.arn
}
```

My Question is how can I reference a policy which is under shared/iam folder to attach it to a role I created in main.tf file under the folder iam-platform-security. The goal is to create policies separately in the shared/iam folder and roles under team/sub-team folders ( like iam-platform-security, iam-platform-architecture,iam-platform-debug etc etc) and then create attachments so policies remains separately as standalone.
Can somebody help me on this.

How can I reference the policy document in main.tf file in different directory.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [modules](https://www.terraform.io/language/modules) so that you can separate your parent TF code from other code, such as your IAM related code in a different folder.

Comment: I have very little knowledge of terraforming. I have just started, but I understand the policy creation role creation and attachment, without modules, can it be done? Or do you have an example for exactly this case scenario so that I can try.

Comment: @sauravdante Sadly if they are in different folders, you have to use modules. I linked TF docs, thus its a good place to start if you have little knowledge on TF.

Comment: I also checked something similar 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48910694/how-to-refer-target-of-another-folder-in-terrform
Can this approach be used?

Comment: @sauravdante Templating is different that what you have. Again, please read docs to learn about TF more.

Comment: Thank you for the docs. If I were to achieve this via templating can aws_iam_role_policy_attachment be used instead of aws_iam_policy_attachment in the above question's answer.
I will try though, thanks.